# Using fillna with groupby with median but its fill few nan values and rest is same Nan values in the dataset

Tags: python, median, fillna

```
data = data.fillna(data.groupby(['product_id'], as_index=False).median())
```

dataset shape is (336666,665). It show 4178 Nan value in 10 columns and few columns have 4.After Executing code its become 3872. Any suggestions regarding this. I have try other code also but that code doing nothing.

```
lx_pmu_p1fh1_slope_x_index_10    4178
lx_pmu_p1fh1_slope_x_index_11    4178
lx_pmu_p1fh1_slope_x_index_12    4178
lx_pmu_p1fh1_slope_x_index_13    4178
lx_pmu_p1fh1_slope_x_index_14    4178
                                 ... 
steering_gear_ratio                 4
steering_wheel_position             4
wheel_base                          4
wheel_brake_type                    4
veh_reg_no                        519
Length: 456, dtype: int64
lx_pmu_p1fh1_slope_x_index_10    3872
lx_pmu_p1fh1_slope_x_index_11    3872
lx_pmu_p1fh1_slope_x_index_12    3872
lx_pmu_p1fh1_slope_x_index_13    3872
lx_pmu_p1fh1_slope_x_index_14    3872
                                 ... 
steering_gear_ratio                 4
steering_wheel_position             4
wheel_base                          4
wheel_brake_type                    4
veh_reg_no                        519
Length: 456, dtype: int64
```

Comment: show some sample data

Comment: @ gold_cy. Dataset is too big. What to show you columns.

Comment: @ gold_cy I have shown the columns before the implementation of code and after the code.